# Does the word "ilus" exist in the Spanish language?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, latín, griego

The Greek word ΙΛΥΣ, written *ilus* in latin characters, means "mud". 
My question is:
Does this word appear anywhere in the Spanish literature?

Comment: Most Spanish words ultimately from Greek were inherited via Latin. This word [doesn't appear to have](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DIlus) been inherited into Latin itself, but the Arabic word إِبْلِيز (ʾiblīz) is possibly derived from Greek ἰλύς (ilús) (alternatively from πηλός (pēlós)). Spanish has a lot of words derived from Arabic loans, though I can't find any derived from this one in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, it doesn't

I have looked for the word in the CORDE and in old dictionaries, but every reference I find to "Ilus" is to a king of Troy. This is attested in the *Terreros y Pando* dictionary from 1787:

> ILUS, ó ILO, cuarto Rei de Troya, hijo de Tros, ó Trois, y de la Ninfa Calirhoe, y que fabricó la Ciudadela de Troya, y echó á Tantalo de su Reino.

This is written in a book from the beginning of the 15th century:

> [...] del rey trous nascio ilus que fizo la mayor fortaleza de troya [...].

Spanish words for *mud* include *barro* and *lodo*.

You can find also some cases of "Ilus." as the abbreviation for *Ilustración*.